# How do I traverse through the a XDocument

Tags: vb.net

I use the following structure to hold my Universe. For each Galaxy holes, a Dictionary of Stars and for each Star holes, a Dictionary of SolBodies.
How do I traverse through the XML and load it into the dictionaries?
Galaxy, Star, SolBody are classes.

```
<Universe>
<Galaxy type="0" name="Galaxy 1">
    <Star type="2" name="Star 1">
        <Body type="5" name="Planet 1"/>
        <Body type="6" name="Planet 2"/>
        <Body type="2" name="Planet 3"/>
        <Body type="6" name="Planet 4"/>
        <Body type="4" name="Planet 5"/>
        <Body type="6" name="Planet 6"/>
        <Body type="3" name="Planet 7"/>
        <Body type="1" name="Planet 8"/>
        <Body type="0" name="Ionstorm 1"/>
        <Body type="0" name="Astroidbelt 1"/>
        <Body type="0" name="Astroidbelt 2"/>
    </Star>
    <Star type="4" name="Star 2">
        <Body type="5" name="Planet 1"/>
        <Body type="6" name="Planet 2"/>
        <Body type="2" name="Planet 3"/>
        <Body type="6" name="Planet 4"/>
        <Body type="4" name="Planet 5"/>
        <Body type="6" name="Planet 6"/>
        <Body type="0" name="Ionstorm 1"/>
        <Body type="0" name="Astroidbelt 1"/>
        <Body type="0" name="Astroidbelt 2"/>
    </Star>
</Galaxy>
<Galaxy type="1" name="Galaxy 2">
    <Star type="2" name="Star 1">
        <Body type="5" name="Planet 1"/>
        <Body type="6" name="Planet 2"/>
        <Body type="2" name="Planet 3"/>
        <Body type="6" name="Planet 4"/>
        <Body type="4" name="Planet 5"/>
        <Body type="0" name="Ionstorm 1"/>
        <Body type="0" name="Astroidbelt 1"/>
        <Body type="0" name="Wormhole 1"/>
    </Star>
</Galaxy>
```

Comment: The easiest way to make this work is to use the built-in XML serialization and deserialization, which may require changes to the data structure to fit the expectations of the framework.  If your data structure is fixed and doesn't fit serialization/deserialization, then you'll need to traverse the children of each element, which are accessible through `Elements` (which is an `IEnumerable(Of XElement)`).